# How can I gather again after say with node.js

Tags: node.js, twilio

I am new to Twilio. I have created a simple program to gather for some input, and say something, and I wrote my program in node.js. May I know how can I ask for audio input again after finish executing '/command' (currently the call will be handed up):

```
// Create a route that will handle Twilio webhook requests, sent as an
// HTTP POST to /voice in our application
app.post('/voice', (request, response) => {
  // Use the Twilio Node.js SDK to build an XML response
  const twiml = new VoiceResponse();

  const gather = twiml.gather({
    input: 'speech',
    speechTimeout: 'auto',
    action: '/command'
});

  gather.say({
    voice: 'alice',
}, 'How can I help');
  // Render the response as XML in reply to the webhook request
  response.type('text/xml');
  response.send(twiml.toString());
});

app.post('/command', (request, response) => {
  // Use the Twilio Node.js SDK to build an XML response
  const twiml = new VoiceResponse();
  twiml.say({
    voice: 'alice'
},request.body.SpeechResult);
  // Render the response as XML in reply to the webhook request
  response.type('text/xml');
  response.send(twiml.toString());

});
```

Answer (score 1):

TO keep the call up (on-going customer dialog), keep responding with Twilio Markup Language (TwiML). The best general document for that is [TwiML™ for Programmable Voice](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml).

You can process the result of the `<Gather>` and then `<Redirect>` to more TwiML. Currently, you are just reading the SpeechResult via the `<Say>` verb and then providing no more TwiML so the call ends.